# How to force creation of backref InstrumentedAttributes using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

In the example below, I want to be able to force the creation of the `parent` attribute on the `Child` class.  Currently, it isn't created until the RelationshipProperty attribute on the `Parent` class that defines the relationship is accessed.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship('Child', backref='parent')


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))


>>> Child.parent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Child' has no attribute 'parent'
>>> Parent.children.property
<RelationshipProperty at 0x3dc3b00; children>
>>> Child.parent
<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x0000000004718F60>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Citing](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlalchemy/ck5ruftRM9Y/Qkh4hPbRDwAJ) Simon King:

> If you want to trigger the creation of all "pending" backref
>   attributes, I think you can call
>   [`sqlalchemy.orm.configure_mappers`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.configure_mappers):
>
> Normally this gets called automatically when you start querying the
>   database, but in certain instances you may want to call it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You want to be able to define the backref to your `Parent` class *in* the `Child` class. SQLAlchemy apparently does not have a very streamlined syntax for accomplishing this, but I believe the following will work:

```
class Parent(base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship(Child, order_by=Child.id, backref='child')

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent = relationship(Parent, backref=backref('children', order_by=id))
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I don't want to instantiate any of the model classes.  I want to *look* at the *field* attributes to present some schema information to the user.  My example shows one method of forcing the creation of the`parent` attribute without having to instantiate the model class.  I'm hoping there is a global way to force the creation of these attributes.

Comment: The only way Child.parent will exist is through Parent. The backref 'parent' is defined in the Parent class, and you did indeed instantiate a Parent and a Child object simply by calling Parent.children.property and Child.parent. Would you mind going into a little more detail about the context of your project? That might make it a little easier to find a solution.

Comment: I want to show schema information, so a user can query a server and find out what fields `Child` has.  One way to do this is to look at the attributes on the SQLAlchemy classes, but in the case of backrefs, the relationship attributes aren't created immediately.  How does accessing a class attribute instantiate a class?  Instantiation requires calling the class, like so -- `Parent()`

Comment: I apologize. You are correct, you were not instantiating an object of class `Parent` by calling the class attribute. I may have a solution. I will edit my answer to illustrate it.